# Expose video streams from M3U playlist through DLNA

Tags: dlna, playlists

Is it possible to somehow expose or share an M3U playlist file via DLNA?

I have a playlist in the standart M3U format, like this:

```
#EXTINF:0 tvg-rec="0",Name of channel
#EXTGRP:France
http://host.tld/iptv/username/channel-id/index.m3u8
# more channels in the same format
```

The goal would be to have a DLNA-server (e.g. MiniDLNA) share this playlist, then being able to browse it from a DLNA-capable TV, select the channel, and have the TV show the stream.

Is this possible with DLNA at all?

Or is there another tool to serve this purpose?

Comment: No, it's not how DLNA works.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it on-the-fly, possibly.

```
mpv --stream-dump="/path/to/dlna/dump.mp4" "/path/to/playlist.m3u"
```

Then, see if you can play `dump.mp4` on the TV.
You may need `dump.webm` if `.mp4` gives you trouble.